# Does "a home" here mean "house" or "homeland"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

Does "a home" here mean "house" or "homeland"?

> This ability to enjoy life is a rich and vital gift. It enables a
> person to bear stress well. It saves us from turning into robots, into
> slaves to either work or worry. It helps us to move from situation to
> situation, from one side of the country to the other and ***find*** ***a home
> there with strangers*** who enjoy what we enjoy

Comment: _Find a home there_ (at the other side of the country) here means 'grow to feel at home there'.

Comment: @KateBunting Does "grow to feel" mean "start to feel"?

Comment: Yes - 'gradually begin to feel'.

Comment: @KateBunting So the sentence can be as "and gradually begin to feel at home with strangers who enjoy what we enjoy"?

Comment: It could be, yes.

Comment: @KateBunting is there another synonym for this?

Comment: For what - _find a home_? Settle down, put down roots...

Comment: @KateBunting yes, you said it means "'gradually begin to feel". so Can we say that "find a home" mean "gradually begin to feel/settle down/put down roots"? The sentence can be also as "and Settle down with strangers who enjoy what we enjoy".

Comment: 'Gradually begin to' was my explanation for 'grow to', which you seemed not to understand. 'Find a home' means 'grow to/begin to/learn to feel [as though you are] at home'.

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you for the explanation. I got it when you told me on 19 Jan. I wanted to know more about it.  Your last comment was really helpful. I really appreciate it.